# Changing active tab's background in C# and XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

OK, I've searched everywhere and in every single link I go to my problem is explained with `xaml` code.

I want to change the active tab's background and foreground (*not its content, but the upper part which you select in order to make active*) in a WPF project, **but I'm looking for the C# code.** The code below doesn't work for me:

```
if (tabs[0].IsEnabled) tabs[0].Background = Brushes.Blue;

else tabs[0].Background = Brushes.Black;
```

Comment: @Venson Because "tabs" is a List<> and it is not in the xaml code.

Comment: You can [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)  to the TabCOntrol's property `ItemsSource`. Than just define a [Styletrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743015.aspx) to change the Background

Comment: I'll make a research and see some exmples on 'bindings', thanks a lot !

Comment: Added as Answer for acceptation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in XAML if you use WPF.

You can [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) to the TabControl's property `ItemsSource`. Than just define a [Styletrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743015.aspx) to change the Background

Answer (score 2):

OK, thanks to `Venson` I've finally got it and just in case someone wants to know how it works:

```
<TabControl  ItemsSource="{Binding tabs}" Height="68" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="156,23,0,0" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="268">
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Border 
                                    Margin="0,0,-4,0" 
                                    Background="Black"
                                    BorderBrush="Blue" 
                                    BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
                                    CornerRadius="2,12,0,0" >
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      ContentSource="Header"
                                      Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"></Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Border 
                                            Margin="0,0,-4,0" 
                                            Background="Green"
                                            BorderBrush="Blue" 
                                            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
                                            CornerRadius="2,12,0,0" >
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              ContentSource="Header"
                                              Margin="12,2,12,2"
                                              RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
```

This code goes in the `<Grid>`of the `<Window>` tags of the `MainWindow.xaml` and

```
public MainWindow()
    {
    testClass testObject = new testClass();

    testObject.tabs = new List<TabItem>();

    testObject.tabs.Add(new TabItem());
    testObject.tabs.Add(new TabItem());

    testObject.tabs[0].Header = "NO WAY";
    testObject.tabs[1].Header = "ON WAY";

    testObject.tabs[0].Content = "WHAT";
    testObject.tabs[1].Content = "HELL";

    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = testObject ;
}
class testClass
{
    public List<TabItem> tabs { set; get; }
}
```

this goes into the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file.

*Please note: the colors are only for the test, don't judge me for the bad contrast chosen!*

I don't know if it's possible not to use another class, though..

Comment: If you really want to use the WPF you should inform yourself about the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)  because it is Possible ;-). Feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var tab in tabs)
{
    tab.Background = tab.IsEnabled ? Brushes.Blue :Brushes.Black;
}
```

But you can handle state of tabcontrol on active tab changes and set backgrounds of deactivated and activated tabs.

Comment: Your exmple doesn't work as well, the tabs turn blue when inactive but still white when active

Comment: How it can be white? I set blue or black. Where you call this code?